# Send email function with Php

Tags: php, function, email

I am sorry to ask suck a trivial thing, but I really do not use php, and I am trying the simplest code to work, to just send an email with no captchas or anything complicated.

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "some-email@live.com"; 
$subject = "New message";

mail($to, $subject, "From: " . $name, $message, "", "");
echo "Your message has been sent";

?>
```

Comment: Ok, What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: @urfusion the email does not reach my email .

Comment: @urfusion Please give the error that you saw on your screen

Comment: @AbdulRahmanASamad : I am not getting any error because this is not my code. :D

Comment: @urfusion you have to turn on "show error" on your PHP installation.

Comment: @urfusion I really do not have an error the echo is printing when submitted, but the email is getting nowhere.

Comment: Using mail() often needs special server configuration. Some webhosts with shared servers even forbid mail(). What's your runtime environment?

Comment: Microsoft is infamous for black-holing mail from servers without reputation.  Either try a different target address, or maybe try https://www.mail-tester.com/.

Comment: @mattGibson Yes, maybe somebody already asked something similar. But not the same.

Comment: @iquellis I have a weird hosting this time with no access to it, I will ask for access.

Comment: @AbdulRahmanASamad To tell you the truth I was trying this directly on the hosting since I really don't use Php to much...

Comment: What does that even mean? :-) You tried with Gmail or not?  Your code shows @live.com. In any case, Gmail is almost as bad - check spam folder but it might just disappear, especially if you are sending from your own development machine.

Comment: Then you all think this code is good?